Script to multiply values in files
I have multiple of text files containing values like this:
width = 64
height = 128
position_x = 48
position_y = 48

I would like to go over this files, and multiply those values by 2, producing a file like this:
width = 128
height = 256
position_x = 96
position_y = 96

Is it possible to make a script for that? What commands can I use to find replace those numbers?

Do those text files only contain lines in the form of key = integer? Can they have different type of lines? Are the lines you want to change are always in the same form? Have you heard of awk?

Are there numeric values anywhere else in the file other than as shown?

perl -pi -e 's/\d+/$& * 2/ge' your-file

Would find all sequences of 1 or more digits and replace them with their value multiplied by 2.
To replace only the <digits> on lines that match the anything = <digits> pattern, replace with:
perl -pi -e 's/ = \K\d+$/$& * 2/ge' your-file


I never saw \K before: does it mean the "real" starting point of  the "search" part (so that only that part is replaced, and $& refers to only what matches after that) ? There are "more common" ways to say "only if this was before", but that way looks cleaner

for exemple (?: = )\d+$ should only match end-of-line digits that were preceded by the string " = " (regex syntax may vary, I'm not 100% sure this one is a PCRE)

@OlivierDulac, yes \K specifies what's to be Kept from the match (what's after it). perldoc perlre for details. (?: = )\d+$ shoud rather be (?<= = )\d+$ but note that in perl look behind operators don't work with variable length matches, using \K doesn't have the problem

Thank you for those clarifications!

Thanks. I managed to make it work with some modifications, because some files have empty space before the lines, and end with a colon. Also some other values were being changed so I only included the ones I need. The final solution was slie this perl -pi -e 's/^( *width| *height| *x| *y) = \K\d+\,*$/$& * 2/ge' your-file
Also to make changes to all of the files I used find
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname "*.dat" | xargs -L1 -I{} perl -pi -e 's/^( *width| *height| *x| *y) = \K\d+\,*$/$& * 2/ge' "{}"

Here's an awk approach:
$ awk '$3 = $3*2' file 
width = 128
height = 256
position_x = 96
position_y = 96

Note that this assumes that the third, whitespace-separated field of the file consists of nothing but digits and is the field you want to multiply. It will also skip any lines whose 3rd field is 0 since we only print in cases where $3*2 evaluates to true, and 0*2 evaluates to false (0). To avoid that, use:
awk '{ $3 = $3*2 } 1' file 

Both of the above may change the input whitespace, converting tabs to spaces for example. I am assuming that isn't relevant here since your example file only has a single space around each =.
